# Problems with control of primefaces components by Managed Bean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I hope somebody could help me with the trouble I am having with JSF 2 and Primefaces 3.0M3.

the problem is that the back bean methods do not fired from any component in the layoutunit 'center' they are inside a form and nothing happens, even I tried to update the components with remoteCommand, autoUpdate of the outputpanel, commandButton with action and actionListener and nothing, there is no error message. In the layoutunit west works the components well, renders the outputpanel (pfpInfo) of the center layoutunit but I do not know what is happening.

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Articulos</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css" />
    <p:layout fullPage="true" id="lay">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="false"
            closable="false" collapsible="false">
            <img src="../images/logo.jpg" alt="PLL"
                style="width: 413px; height: 83px;" align="left"></img>ss
            <img src="../images/tel.jpg" alt="PLR"
                style="width: 413px; height: 83px;" align="right"></img>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header="Categorías"
            resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false">
            <h:form id="frWest">
                <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" globalOnly="true"
                    autoUpdate="true"></p:growl>
                <p:tree id="treeSingle" value="#{controlMBean.raizArbol}"
                    var="rama" dynamic="true" selectionMode="single"
                    selection="#{controlMBean.ramaElegida}" expanded="true">
                    <p:ajax event="select"
                        update=":frCenter:pfSeg :frCenter:pfpInfo :frCenter:pfpIma"
                        listener="#{controlMBean.procesaInformacionArt}"></p:ajax>
                    <p:treeNode>
                        <h:outputText value="#{rama}" styleClass="encabezadoUiLight" />
                    </p:treeNode>
                </p:tree>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:form id="frCenter">
                <p:outputPanel id="pfSeg" rendered="true">
                    <p:outputPanel id="pfpIma" rendered="#{not controlMBean.cargado}">
                        <img src="../images/luchadores.jpg" />
                    </p:outputPanel>

                    <p:outputPanel id="pfpInfo" rendered="#{controlMBean.cargado}"
                        autoUpdate="true">

                        <p:dataTable dynamic="true" var="prnda" rowKey="#{prnda.id}"
                            value="#{controlMBean.infoArts}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                            selectionMode="single" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                            selection="#{controlMBean.artElegido}"
                            rendered="#{controlMBean.cargado}">
                            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect"
                                listener="#{prestalana.deseleccionar}"></p:ajax>
                            <f:facet name="header">Articulo(s)</f:facet>
                            <p:ajax update=":frCenter:ppImg :frCenter:pgInfo"
                                oncomplete="prnd.show()" event="rowSelect"
                                listener="#{controlMBean.elegirFila}"></p:ajax>
                            <p:column sortBy="#{prnda.id}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Id" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{prnda.id}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column sortBy="#{prnda.articulo}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Modelo" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{prnda.articulo}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column sortBy="#{prnda.marca}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Marca" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{prnda.marca}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column sortBy="#{prnda.edo}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Ubicación" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{prnda.edo}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column sortBy="#{prnda.stsArticulo}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Estatus" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{prnda.stsArticulo} " />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column sortBy="#{prnda.precio}">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Precio" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="$ #{prnda.precio}" />
                            </p:column>

                        </p:dataTable>
                        <p:commandButton action="#{controlMBean.probar2}"
                            actionListener="#{controlMBean.probar}" value="Prueba"></p:commandButton>

                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <br />
                    <h:outputText value="#{controlMBean.mensaje}"
                        styleClass="textoUiLight" id="hotMen" />
                </p:outputPanel>
                <p:remoteCommand actionListener="#{controlMBean.probar}"
                    name="pruebaRc" update=":frCenter:ppImg"></p:remoteCommand>
                <p:dialog appendToBody="true" dynamic="true" header="Info Prenda"
                    onShow="pruebaRc" widgetVar="prnd" resizable="false" width="750"
                    height="550" showEffect="fold" position="center"
                    hideEffect="explode">
                    <p:outputPanel id="ppImg" autoUpdate="true">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="pgInfo">
                            <p:galleria transitionInterval="3000" var="i"
                                value="#{controlMBean.imagenes}"
                                panelWidth="#{controlMBean.width}"
                                panelHeight="#{controlMBean.height}"
                                frameHeight="#{controlMBean.height/4}"
                                frameWidth="#{controlMBean.width/4}" effect="flash">
                                <p:graphicImage id="img" height="#{i.alto}" width="#{i.ancho}"
                                    value="#{controlMBean.ruta}#{i.nombre}.jpg" />
                            </p:galleria>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="350">
                                <h:outputLabel value="ID:" styleClass="etiqueta" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{controlMBean.artElegido.id}"
                                    styleClass="resultado" />
                                <h:outputLabel value="Prenda:" styleClass="etiqueta" />
                                <h:outputText
                                    value="#{controlMBean.artElegido.prenda} adasd"
                                    styleClass="resultado" />
                                <h:outputLabel value="Precio:" styleClass="etiqueta" />
                                <h:outputText value="$#{controlMBean.artElegido.precio}"
                                    styleClass="resultado" />
                                <h:outputLabel value="Marca:" styleClass="etiqueta" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{controlMBean.artElegido.marca}"
                                    styleClass="resultado" />
                                <h:outputLabel value="Sucursal:" styleClass="etiqueta" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{controlMBean.artElegido.suc}"
                                    styleClass="resultado" />
                                <h:outputLabel value="Descripcion:" styleClass="etiqueta" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{controlMBean.artElegido.descr}"
                                    styleClass="resultado" style="width:300px;height:100px;" />
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>

    </p:layout>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am also having a similar issue.